# How to join in flink with State Time-To-Live (TTL)

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

In a Flink job, I read a Kafka stream and apply some joins before saving the data in a database. Kafka topic contains two types of data, so I first join both records, create a single row, and save it into the database. I need the latest data to be stored in the database.

for example -

```
{"id":1, "item":"1", "amount":300, "type":"revenue"}
{"id":1, "item":"1", "amount":30, "type":"profit"}
```

I need the data in the table

```
id | item | revenue | profit
1  |  1   | 300     | 30
```

I am creating a createTemporaryView ("tableA") on top of the Kafka source and then applying the below-joining logic

```
Table tr = tableEnv.sqlQuery("select " +
            " coalesce(a.id, b.id) id," +
            " coalesce(a.item, b.item) item," +
            " a.amount as revenue," +
            " b.amount as profit" +
            " from " +
            " (select * from tableA" +
            " where type='revenue') a" +
            " full outer join " +
            " (select * from tableA" +
            " where type='profit') b" +
            " on a.id=b.id, a.item=b.item");
```

Lastly, save the data in the table. It is working fine. The flink maintains all the state of the join. If id=1 comes 100 times, then flink maintains 100 entries in its state. As a result, a memory problem will arise

Flink is new to me, do we have any setting (TTL) to ensure that it only maintains the last updated value and removes all previous states? In addition, how to configure rockDB settings to maintain robust storage for this state.

flink version : 1.13.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flink's state TTL mechanism doesn't have the right behavior for this use case. State TTL keeps too much state, as it retains all recent state, rather than only the most recent state. And worse, it drops the most recent state when it is no longer recent enough.

One of the Immerok Apache Flink Cookbook recipes covers this case; see the [streaming table workflow](https://www.docs.immerok.cloud/docs/cookbook/serializing-timestamped-data/#the-table-workflow) in [this recipe about keeping track of each customer's most recent transaction](https://github.com/immerok/recipes/tree/main/latest-transaction). This is an example of a [top-n query](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/topn/#top-n), where n equals 1:

```sql
SELECT [column_list]
FROM (
   SELECT [column_list],
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER ([PARTITION BY col1[, col2...]]
       ORDER BY time_attr DESC AS rownum
   FROM table_name)
WHERE rownum = 1
```

The key here is expressing the constraint in the query itself, so that the SQL engine creates a plan that only retains the necessary state.

Disclaimer: I work for Immerok.

Comment: As I am using 2 tables so I need to use the row_number logic in both of the tables before joining. Also, you said Flink drops the most recent state when it is no longer recent enough. So how to handle that? We don't know when the again customer data comes. In that case, it will nullify the result of joining.

Comment: Flink drops the most recent state when it is no longer recent enough _if you use state TTL_. You don't want to use state TTL.

Comment: After adding  ROW_NUMBER . I am getting Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: The window can only be ordered in ASCENDING mode. I added .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks()); but still same error

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong. It can work, but the query has to be recognized by the planner as a deduplication or top-n query, rather than some arbitrary over aggregation involving time. https://github.com/immerok/recipes/blob/main/latest-transaction/src/main/java/com/immerok/cookbook/workflows/TableWorkflow.java is an example you can run that works. This test runs that query: https://github.com/immerok/recipes/blob/main/latest-transaction/src/test/java/com/immerok/cookbook/LatestTransactionTest.java#L54

Comment: It works fine, but Flink flushes all records every few minutes. As I save the data to the apache hudi table, I see the same records are flushed every few minutes. How can we stop these things so that Flink only runs join logic on new records?